# HTTP JSON API request responds "-1"

Tags: php, json, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to make a REST API that an Arduino with an ESP8266 module can `GET`, but when I try to send a request to my server the HTTP Code that I get is `-1`, which I have not been able to find any documentation on anywhere (it's not in the list of HTTP status codes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)).

My test-API that I get the `-1` response from is [here](https://makerspace.albe.pw/api/getDoorStatus.php), while a [this](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1) API works fine. My API is simple:

PHP API:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 

$array = array(
    "status" => true
);

echo json_encode($array);
```

The **Arduino code** is just one of the ESP8266 examples, and looks like this:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "Next-Guest";
const char* password = "";

void setup () {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {

    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("Connecting..");

  }

}

void loop() {
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    HTTPClient http;

    //http.begin("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1"); <- this works
    http.begin("https://makerspace.albe.pw/api/getDoorStatus.php"); // <- this doesn't
    int httpCode = http.GET();

    Serial.println(httpCode);
    if (httpCode > 0) {
      String payload = http.getString();
      Serial.println(payload);
    }
    http.end();
  }
  delay(30000);
}
```

I can do a GET request locally from any computer to my API using jQuery AJAX, so it must be somewhat open?

Is my host the problem, or are my files missing some headers?

Comment: Putting `http_response_code(200);` there will cause an issue as your sending output, try moving it above the `echo`.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Whether the response is there or not, or where I place it hasn't made a difference from what I've tested. Exactly the same result.

Comment: Does it work with the commented out url? The issue may be with https.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes the commented out url works fine

Comment: Not sure, but I think for https, you need to supply a foot print. [Simple GET request with ESP8266HTTPClient](//arduino.stackexchange.com/a/45679)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Actually you might be right about `https` being the problem. When I try to access some of my subdomains that doesn't have a SSL certificate, it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing a domain protected with a SSL certificate (https), you need to specify the SSL thumbprint as a second parameter in the `http.begin` function:

```
String thumbprint = "the_thumbprint";
http.begin("https://api.site/api/get_details.json", thumbprint);
```